error mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x256 and 768x1280) while fine tuning stable video diffusion
I want to fine tune a stable diffusion model with my dataset. Getting error on line  output = lora_unet
model used: stable-video-diffusion-img2vid-xt-1-1
Tried some code fixes given by chatgpt but no use. This is the shape of parameters.
Frames shape: torch.Size([4, 60, 3, 128, 128])
Timesteps shape: torch.Size([4])
Encoder hidden states shape: torch.Size([4, 768])
Added time IDs shape: torch.Size([4, 1])

The error I am getting is
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x256 and 768x1280)

How to fix the issue?
for frames, labels in tqdm(alphabet_loader):
    frames = frames.to(device)

    # Create a label mapping and numerical labels
    label_mapping = {label: idx for idx, label in enumerate(labels)}
    numeric_labels = [label_mapping[label] for label in labels]
    labels = torch.tensor(numeric_labels).to(device)

    # Random timesteps (typically, a value between 0 and 1000 for diffusion models)
    timesteps = torch.randint(0, 1000, (frames.size(0),), device=device)

    # Number of classes and embedding dimension
    num_classes = len(label_mapping)
    embedding_dim = 256  # Your current embedding size (this can remain 256 for the embedding)
    label_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_classes, embedding_dim).to(device)

    # Generate encoder hidden states from label embeddings
    encoder_hidden_states = label_embedding(labels)  # Shape: [batch_size, num_labels]

    # Project the encoder hidden states to the required dimension (768)
    projection_layer = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, 768).to(device)  # Project from 256 to 768
    encoder_hidden_states = projection_layer(encoder_hidden_states)  # Now shape is [batch_size, 768]

    # Added time IDs (optional, adjust as needed)
    added_time_ids = torch.zeros_like(timesteps, device=device)
    added_time_ids = added_time_ids.unsqueeze(-1)  # Convert [batch_size] to [batch_size, 1]

    # Permute frames to the expected shape [batch_size, timesteps, channels, height, width]
    #frames = frames.permute(0, 2, 1, 3, 4)  # [B, T, C, H, W] -> [B, T, C, H, W]
    
    # Print shapes for debugging
    print(f"Frames shape: {frames.shape}")
    print(f"Timesteps shape: {timesteps.shape}")
    print(f"Encoder hidden states shape: {encoder_hidden_states.shape}")
    print(f"Added time IDs shape: {added_time_ids.shape}")

    # Forward pass
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = lora_unet(
        frames,
        timestep=timesteps,
        encoder_hidden_states=encoder_hidden_states,
        added_time_ids=added_time_ids,
    )["sample"]
    
    # Compute the loss (ensure labels are in float format for MSELoss)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    loss = criterion(output, labels.float())  # Ensure type compatibility
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    epoch_loss += loss.item()

Stacktrace :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/main.py", line 71, in 
cli.main()
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 501, in main
run()
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 351, in run_file
runpy.run_path(target, run_name="main")
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 310, in run_path
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 127, in _run_module_code
_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals, mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.14.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 118, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Users/sunaynatalreja//FrontEnd/.py", line 288, in 
output = lora_unet(
^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py", line 849, in forward
return self.get_base_model()(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/diffusers/models/unets/unet_spatio_temporal_condition.py", line 429, in forward
aug_emb = self.add_embedding(time_embeds)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/diffusers/models/embeddings.py", line 1304, in forward
sample = self.linear_1(sample)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 125, in forward
return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x256 and 768x1280)

Please update the question with full traceback if possible. This is most likely due to input shape mismatch. While CNN architecture do not constrain the spatial input size, there maybe other layers that require specific shape.
